# C++ Library Organization

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, organization

I'm building a very basic library, and it's the first project that I plan on releasing for others to use if they'd like. As such, I'd like to know what some "best practices" as far as organization goes. The only thing that may be unique about my project is that in order for it to be used in a project, users would be required to extend certain abstract classes, which leads me to my first question:

- **A lot of libraries I've seen consist of a .a file and a single .h file. Is this best practice? Wouldn't it be better to expose all the public .h files so that users can choose which ones to include? If this is the preferred way of doing things, how exactly is it accomplished? What goes into that single .h file?**

My second question involves dependencies. For example my current project relies on OpenGL, GLFW, and GLEW. **Should I package those in some way with my project, or just make it the user's responsibility to ensure that they are installed?**

Edit: Someone asked about my target OS. All of my dependencies are cross platform so I'm (perhaps naively) hoping to make my library cross platform as well.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: first of all: what license type your library have? and what is a target OS?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard best practices here.  Personally, I like to have one header file for each public class, even if it is in a library.  Some people might think it is a waste of time having to include all those individual files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the circumstances. If you have some fairly complex functionality, that are in a number of closely related functions, then one header is the right solution.

E.g. you write a set of functions that draw something to the screen, and you need a few functions to confgiure/set up the environment, a few functions to define and place objects in the scene, a few functions to do the actual drawing/processing, and finally teardown, then using one header file is a good plan.

In the above case, it's also possible to have one "overall" header-file that includes several smaller ones. Particularly if you have fairly large classes, sticking them all in one file gets rather messy.

On the other hand, if you have one set of functions that deal with gasses dissolved in liquids, another set of functions to calculate the strength/load capacity of a steel beam, and another set of functions to calculate the friction of a rubber tyre against a roadsurface, then they probably should have different headers - even if it's all feasible functionality to go in a "Physics/mechanics library".

It is rarely a good idea to supply third party libraries with your library - yes, if you want to offer two downloads, one with the "all you nead, just add water", and one "bare library", that's fine. But I don't want to spend three times longer than necessary to download your library, simply because it also contains three other libraries that your code is using, which is already on my machine. However, do document what libraries are needed, and what you need to do to install them on your supported platforms (and what the supported platforms are). And what versions of libraries you have tested - there's nothing worse than "getting the latest", only to find that the version something needs is two steps back...

(And as Jason C points out, licensing gets very messy once you have a few different packages that your code depends on, because your license then has to be compatible with ALL the other licenses - sometimes that's not even possible...)

Comment: Another big reason to not package third-party libraries is many libraries licensing terms specifically prohibit packaging the library with another application.

Answer (score 1):

You have options and it really depends on how convenient you choose to make it for developers using your libraries.

As for the headers, the general method for libraries of average complexity is to have a single header that a developer can include to get everything they need. A good method is, if you have multiple headers, create a single header with the same name as your library (not required, just common) and have it #include all the individual headers. Then distribute the single header and individual headers. That way your users have the option of #including just one to get everything, or #including individual ones if necessary.

E.g. in mylibrary.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H
#define MYLIBRARY_H

#include <mylibrary/something.h>
#include <mylibrary/another.h>
#include <mylibrary/lastone.h>

#endif
```

Ensure that your individual headers can be included standalone (i.e. they #include everything they need) if you want to provide that option to developers.

As for dependencies, you will want to make it the user's responsibility to ensure they are installed. The user is compiling their code and linking to your library, and so it is also the user's responsibility to link to dependent libraries. If you package third-party dependencies with your library you run many risks:

1. Breaking user's systems who already have dependencies installed.
2. As mentioned in Mats Petersson's answer, forcing users to download dependencies they already have.
3. Violating licensing rights on third-party libraries.

The best thing for you to do is clearly document the required dependencies.

For this there are not really standard "best practices". Any sane practice would be a good practice.

Comment: Added point 2 to list above as Mats pointed out.

Comment: I accepted Mats' answer because it was slightly more detailed, but your answer was also very helpful. I hadn't even thought of the licensing issues.

Comment: I like Mats' answer better too.